# FB share feature on Swift

Tags: swift, facebook

I am implementing FB share feature on iOS app using Swift, the module I am using is 'Facebookshare', I already got it right but I need to know the result. It seems like everytime one window pops up, and when I post or cancel, the window goes down and no return value back to me. I need to know whether it is posted or cancelled by the user, so how should I correct my codes? 
Any ideas will be appreciated.
The codes related:

```
import FacebookShare

let urlToGet = //urlToGetTheContent 
let content = LinkShareContent(url: NSURL(string: urlToGet)! as URL)
 do { let x = try ShareDialog.show(from: self, content: content)
      print(x) //x is to show the status, but it is always 'FacebookShare.ShareDialog<FacebookShare.LinkShareContent>'
      } catch {
      //handling errors
        }
```

Also, I have seen the example on the Facebook official website, though it can be compiled, my app always crash when executes the code, so I didn't use it. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/graph-api

Does anybody know how to correct codes in the doc so it works? Then I think my problem is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little confusing because the ShareDialog class has a static `show` method as well as an instance method of the same name. In your code fragment you are accessing the static (class level) function version `ShareDialog.show` (note the upper case s).

Read the section on [Sharing With The Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/share-dialog) to see a code fragment which calls the instance method `shareDialog.show` (note the lower case s).  The example code shows how to specify a completion handler to process the result you are looking for which will be of type ContentSharerResult (an enum comprising Success, Failed, Cancelled).

By the way, the static func also accepts a completion handler as an optional argument, defaulting to nil. You could use that if you prefer and are comfortable with the closure syntax. Otherwise, use the instance method as illustrated in the link.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! The issue is now fixed.